# My Twitter account says I have 17 tweets but I have 0

Tags: twitter

This is my Twitter page:

[image]

Why does it say I have 17 tweets, but I have 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted tweets don't always get reflected in your tweet count, particularly if you are using a tool to delete them. There is [a thread on the Twitter discussion forum](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15071) full of people with this issue.

In [this older discussion forum post](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7247), a Twitter employee suggests:

> This happens sometimes when users bulk delete their tweets. Your account needs to assistance from support to clear it up. Reach out to @[support](https://twitter.com/Support) through https://support.twitter.com as we cannot assist here.